# Font Awesome icons are not showing up in my code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

Here is my code. I am currently building a website and got stuck in the first step itself.

According to the tutorial that I am following, two icons should show up in the window but I just get a blank white screen.

```html
  <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Eventors | Events</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="hamburger-menu">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars toggle"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-times toggle"></i>
                </div> 
                <nav>
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="">
                    </a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
    
    
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ba33ab971e.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you please tell us where should the two icons show up ? There is only one img src in your code.

Comment: are you sure about you kit number, https://kit.fontawesome.com/ba33ab971e.js the file isn't loading

Comment: You should create your own account on FontAwesome and create a kit

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have no experience with bootstrapping.

Answer (score 2):

Your FontAwesome link is not working. 
Change `<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ba33ab971e.js"></script>` with a correct import tag and it'll be fine.

I've tried with mine and everything else works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help everyone.

The problem was in the way FontAwesome was called in the code, just like you guys pointed out.

I followed this article https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_intro.asp to make corrections.

I added  in the head of my HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the restricted link you are using for fontawesome.
Try to replace the "https://kit.fontawesome.com/ba33ab971e.js" with "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js".

Comment: I was having same issue working with Angular 10 and Dotnet Core 3.1 and this answer solved the issue.